# HttpWebRequest returns 403 in Windows Server 2019 to url:microsoft.com

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest, tpm

I am trying to make a **web request** to microsoft.com (either http, https) in **windows 11** succeeds but in **windows server 2019** returns **403**. Below, is the code:

```cs
var uri = new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com");
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.Method = "GET";

request.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko";

request.Accept = "application/xml";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";

request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var webResponseStatusCode = response.StatusCode;

    Console.WriteLine("it works - " + webResponseStatusCode);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

I also tried with the **ServerCertificateValidationCallback** callback if there was an error there, and also with different user agents the result is the same. I suspect that because the **TLS1.3** is not supported in **windows server 2019** it may cause this issue, but this is the issue then how can this fixed? (trying to enable the tls1.3 via registry keys made the VM not reachable with RDP).

*Also only microsoft.com url I have found with the 403 error. Other url's like google.com returns 200 OK.*

Any ideas?

Comment: A Tls problem would surface differently. A 403 is an authentication error. You are forbidden to see whats at the end of the url. Have you checked that you are actually talking to the expected endpoint? Or is there something in between like a Proxy that forbids?

Comment: Agreed this is not from TLS1.3. Check proxies, firewalls, etc. Why don't you use the newer `HttpClient`?

Comment: Is it possible that this might be relevant with the absence of TPM2.0? Because I don't see the windows server 2019 to have any.

Comment: With HttpClient it works, but also in my provided example only if the user agent is empty.